# Qt Connection to DB2

Tags: qt, db2, odbc

As a test I tried connecting to a DB2 server using the QODBC driver. I did this by creating a DSN and then providing the needed data such as hostname and the rest.

But what if I want to run my app in another computer. Is there another way to connect to a DB2 database, because as I see it this would also limit me if I tried to compile and run my program in iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use QSqlDatabase class like this:

```
bool createConnection()
{
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QDB2");
    db.setHostName("mozart.konkordia.edu");
    db.setDatabaseName("musicdb");
    db.setUserName("gbatstone");
    db.setPassword("T17aV44");
    if (!db.open()) {
        QMessageBox::critical(0, QObject::tr("Database Error"),
                              db.lastError().text());
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

[EDITED]

**How to Build the QDB2 Plugin on Windows**

The DB2 header and include files should already be installed in the right directories. You just have to build the plugin as follows:

```
 cd %QTDIR%\src\plugins\sqldrivers\db2
 qmake "INCLUDEPATH+=<DB2 home>/sqllib/include" "LIBS+=<DB2 home>/sqllib/lib/db2cli.lib"
 nmake
```

Comment: That is what I did with databases such as Postgres or MySQL, but there is no QDB2 driver in Qt5 I think.

Comment: Take a look: http://qt.developpez.com/doc/5.0-snapshot/qsqldatabase/ (Driver type QDB2)

Comment: I see, still though by running **QSqlDatabase::drivers();** I get the following list *("QSQLITE", "QMYSQL", "QMYSQL3", "QODBC", "QODBC3", "QPSQL", "QPSQL7")* on iOS and Windows. Should I have checked something during installation or do I have to find the drivers myself.

Comment: Take a look: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/sql-driver.html#qdb2 . I have also edited my answer added the information about building the plugin

Comment: Ok so I need to compile them myself got it.